# WPF FlowDocumentScrollViewer automatically scroll to bottom of the document

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

I have a UserControl that the XAML looks like:

```
<Grid>
    <FlowDocumentScrollViewer Name="ProvisionStatusMonitor" Document="{Binding Document}" SourceUpdated="OnSourceUpdated"/>
</Grid>
```

The code-behind looks like

```
    private void OnSourceUpdated(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
    {
        FlowDocumentScrollViewer docViewer = (FlowDocumentScrollViewer) sender;

        var scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)docViewer.Template
            .FindName("ProvisionStatusMonitor", docViewer);

        scrollViewer.ScrollToEnd();
    }
```

But this doesn't seem to work. When the document is changed I was thinking that this event should fire and I could automatically scroll to the bottom of the document. What am I missing?

Comment: `"ProvisionStatusMonitor"` is wrong. It must be `"PART_ContentHost"`. It is a component inside the visual tree of the FlowDocumentScrollViewer.

Comment: What makes you think that `SourceUpdated` would be called? The Binding source never changes.

Comment: @Clemens I was looking at the possible events that are associated with FlowDocumentScrollViewer and SourceUpdated was the closest that I came up with. So how should the XAML look like? I need to put something on the XAML to indicate that there is some code-behind to be called.

Comment: You may attach the DataContextChanged event shown in the answer in XAML instead of the StatusView constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may attach a PropertyChanged event handler to the view model in a DataContextChanged handler in the view.

Assuming that `StatusView` is a UserControl that contains the FlowDocumentScrollViewer shown in the question, it could look like this:

```
public StatusView()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DataContextChanged += StatusViewDataContextChanged;
}

private void StatusViewDataContextChanged(
    object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OldValue is INotifyPropertyChanged oldViewModel)
    {
        oldViewModel.PropertyChanged -= ViewModelPropertyChanged;
    }

    if (e.NewValue is INotifyPropertyChanged newViewModel)
    {
        newViewModel.PropertyChanged += ViewModelPropertyChanged;
    }
}

private void ViewModelPropertyChanged(
    object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "Document")
    {
        var docViewer = ProvisionStatusMonitor;

        var scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)docViewer.Template
            .FindName("PART_ContentHost", docViewer);

        scrollViewer.ScrollToEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: I obviously have a PropertyChanged notification that is raised when the document is updated. Since I have this setup already (as you noted as part of the DataContext) how do I ensure that the notification that is raised in the view model handled in the view? Where does `viewModel.PropertyChanged += ViewModelPropertyChanged;` go so that it is handled? In my case the view model is assigned to the view as a result of a resource like
        `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type views:StatusViewModel}">
            <views:StatusView/>
        </DataTemplate>`
PropertyChanged isn't there.

Comment: So this is indicating that I raise an event that the document has changed (which is already being done). And since the view model is the DataContext I would essentially do this in the constructor `this.PropertyChanged += ViewModelPropertyChanged`

Comment: One other concern. Isn't this essentially polluting the view model? Since to resolve the reference to FlowDocumentScrollViewer I need to pull in System.Windows?

Comment: You would of course (still) not do this in the view model. As said in a comment to one of your previous questions, scrolling is done in the view. The PropertyChanged event handler could be attached in DataContextChanged event handler in StatusView - assuming that StatusView is the element that contains the FlowDocumentScrollViewer.